# como cambiar el valor de "action" de un form de forma dinámica

Tags: javascript, php, html

Estoy realizando un formulario el cual dependiendo el tipo de documento que selecciona con anterioridad y que traigo por la url, genera un documento pdf. Para esto cree una función en js la cual toma el id de documento y el formulario y se supone que dependiendo el documento que seleccione este lo validaría y cambiaria el valor del action="" con la ruta correspondiente al documento

```
if (isset($_GET['documento_seleccionado']) && isset($_GET['nombre']) && isset($_GET['notaria_seleccionada']) && isset($_GET['nombrenot']) && isset($_GET['direccion']) && isset($_GET['comuna']) && isset($_GET['hora']) && isset($_GET['dia']) && isset($_GET['mes']) && isset($_GET['anio'])) {

  $documento_seleccionado = $_GET['documento_seleccionado'];
  $nombre = $_GET['nombre'];
  $notaria_seleccionada = $_GET['notaria_seleccionada'];
  $nombrenot = $_GET['nombrenot'];
  $direccion = urldecode($_GET['direccion']);
  $comuna = $_GET['comuna'];
  $hora = $_GET['hora'];
  $fecha_seleccionada = $_GET['dia'];
  $mes = $_GET['mes'];
  $anio = $_GET['anio'];
?>
```

```
 <section>
      <div class="row justify-content-center align-text-left" style="margin-left: 60px; margin-right: 60px;">
        <?php echo
        "<form id='formulario' class='border shadow row' method='post' action='$tipoDocumento?notaria_seleccionada=$notaria_seleccionada&nombre=$nombre&comuna=$comuna&hora=$h&dia=$fecha_seleccionada&correo=$correo'>"; ?>
        <h4 style="margin-top: 20px;"><b>Datos del solicitante</b></h4>
        <br><br><br>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 ">
          <label for="name">Nombres</label>
          <input type="text" name="nombres" class="form-control" id="nombres" required>
        </div>
 <div class="section">
          <button name="botondatos" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary contact aceptarButton text-bold">Continuar</button>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        </form>

      </div>
    </section>
```

Ese es el codigo donde esta el formulario y en la parte de action estaba tratando de llamarlo como $tipoDocumento pero que claramente no funciona . este es mi js para que lo vean

```
    function cambiarAction() {
      var tipoDocumento = document.getElementById("documento_seleccionado").value;
      var formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");

      if (tipoDocumento === "15") {
        formulario.action = "documentosPDF/adminInmueblepdf.php";
      } else if (tipoDocumento === "40") {
        formulario.action = "documentosPDF/adminPublicapdf.php";
      } else if (tipoDocumento === "28") {
        formulario.action = "documentosPDF/CarroArrastrepdf.php";
      } else if (tipoDocumento === "29") {
        formulario.action = "documentosPDF/cesantiapdf.php";
      } else if (tipoDocumento === "25") {
        formulario.action = "documentosPDF/compraVentapdf.php";
      } else if (tipoDocumento === "32") {
        formulario.action = "documentosPDF/expensaspdf.php";}}
```

Comment: Dudo que esto responda a tu pregunta, pero no veo que estés definiendo la variable `$tipoDocumento` en tu código PHP...

Comment: justamente , pensaba que con solo poner el  ´´´<script src="cambiarAction.js"></script> ´´´ iba a funcionar pero me di cuenta que no y vine a consultar por aca

Comment: No sé, pero creo que te estás liando sin necesidad. ¿Por qué quieres cambiar el action? ¿No es mejor mandar todo a la misma ruta (mismo action) y en el servidor, según el tipo de documento, decidir lo que hay que hacer?

Comment: MMM. es que tengo un archivo .php que genera un documento pdf dependiendo el tipo de documento se asigna el .php que tiene la plantilla de este y son mas de 20 archivos por eso lo quería hacer de esta forma . no se si me puede ayudar con alguna otra forma que creas que sea mejor